# Save and Export into Stata using R tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I have the code below, where I imported the dataset as a Stata file

```
library(haven)
> LMI_MENA <- read_dta("Impact on Employment/LMI_MENA.dta")
```

Then made the data wrangling below:

```
LMI_MENA %>%
  pivot_longer(fem_unemployment:male_emp, names_to = "names", values_to = "values") %>%
  mutate(Gender = case_when(
    str_detect(names, "fem") ~ "Female",
    str_detect(names, "male") ~ "Male",
    TRUE ~ "Total"
  )) %>%
  mutate(names = case_when(
    names %in% c("fem_unemployment", "male_unemployment", "urate") ~ "Unemployment",
    names %in% c("lfprate", "female_lfp", "male_lfp") ~ "LaborForceParticipation",
    names %in% c("fem_emp", "male_emp") ~ "Employment"
  )) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "names", values_from = "values")
```

And I tried to save the edited dataset and export it directly into Stata

```
DF <- data.frame
      write.dta(LMI_MENA, file="LMI_MENA_long.dta")
```

However, while it exports correctly, it does not show the newly created variables from the data wrangling above. What is the best way to save and then to export to Stata, csv, etc..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you provide a reproducible example. It appears that you just saved your original Stata file back to Stata because you did not assign the dataset with new variable to the R object.

In the first line of your code before `LMI_MENA %>%`, add `LMI_MENA <- LMI_MENA %>%`.

```
LMI_MENA <- LMI_MENA %>%
  pivot_longer(fem_unemployment:male_emp, names_to = "names", values_to = "values") %>%
  mutate(Gender = case_when(
    str_detect(names, "fem") ~ "Female",
    str_detect(names, "male") ~ "Male",
    TRUE ~ "Total"
  )) %>%
  mutate(names = case_when(
    names %in% c("fem_unemployment", "male_unemployment", "urate") ~ "Unemployment",
    names %in% c("lfprate", "female_lfp", "male_lfp") ~ "LaborForceParticipation",
    names %in% c("fem_emp", "male_emp") ~ "Employment"
  )) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "names", values_from = "values")
```